# how can i add lastaccess time in command Get-ItemProperty

Tags: powershell, scripting

How can I add lastaccess time in this command:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: I don't see a property named `LastAccessTime` in the registry using `Get-ItemProperty` or `Get-ChildItem`. Apparently there's a `LastWriteTime` property but it's not trivial to retrieve, more reading here: https://learn-powershell.net/2014/12/18/retrieving-a-registry-key-lastwritetime-using-powershell/

Comment: can you edit this command so that i can get the last write time as well in it  Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table -AutoSize @codaamok

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't. To see all properties you can choose from run the following command:

```
 Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | gm
```

It will show all the fields you can get info out of.

```
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name            MemberType   Definition
----            ----------   ----------
Equals          Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode     Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType         Method       type GetType()
ToString        Method       string ToString()
DisplayIcon     NoteProperty string DisplayIcon=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Commo...
DisplayName     NoteProperty string DisplayName=Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
DisplayVersion  NoteProperty string DisplayVersion=16.2.29209.62
InstallDate     NoteProperty string InstallDate=20190715
InstallLocation NoteProperty string InstallLocation=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise
ModifyPath      NoteProperty string ModifyPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installe...
PSChildName     NoteProperty string PSChildName=18bd80bd
PSDrive         NoteProperty PSDriveInfo PSDrive=HKLM
PSParentPath    NoteProperty string PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow...
PSPath          NoteProperty string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432No...
PSProvider      NoteProperty ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
Publisher       NoteProperty string Publisher=Microsoft Corporation
RepairPath      NoteProperty string RepairPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installe...
UninstallString NoteProperty string UninstallString="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_ins...
```

LastAccessTime is no property of registry items.

Maybe you can use the install path and get the ItemProperties of the executable in there to figure out when the software is used for the last time.

Comment: can you please give me that script which will show me last access lime with these given things

Comment: I cannot. The information simply isn't there. The above properties is all that you can retrieve from registry entries.

Comment: can you tell me any command which can tell me last access time and installed date together